# Typo3 with MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, typo3

I am interested in the question whether TYPO3 can work on the basis of MSSQL and are there any pitfalls? Since I cannot find this information on the official site.

Understanding that PDO supports MSSQL and TYPO3 works through the driver, can you do it yourself or is there a ready-made driver for this?

Comment: Also, https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/guide-installation/9.5/en-us/In-depth/SystemRequirements/Index.html lists that option

Comment: Also, https://get.typo3.org/version/11 lists that option - so, where did you look instead?

Comment: The TYPO3 should be compatible with MS SQL, but that doesn't necessarily mean that all public extensions from The TYPO3 Extension Repository are compatible as well.